# A proof for $[(f^k)^{(n)}]^2 \geq (f^{k-1})^{(n)} (f^{k+1})^{(n)}$

Tags: calculus

I want to show $[(f^k)^{(n)}]^2 \geq (f^{k-1})^{(n)} (f^{k+1})^{(n)}$, where $f$ satisfies $f^{(n)} \geq 0$ for all integer $n$ and $f^k$ denotes the $k$-th power of $f$.

I believe it's right but I can't see it clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you miss a square on the left side? $[(f^k)^{(n)}]^2\ge(f^{k-1})^{(n)}(f^{k+1})^{(n)}$ is at least invariant under scaling of $f$.

Comment: @LutzL It is..sorry I have made a mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It is not true. Let $f(x)=e^x$. Then $f^{(n)}(x)=e^x>0$ for all $x$ and all $n$. $f^k(x)=e^{kx}$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
(f^k)^{(n)}&=k^n\,e^{kx}\\
(f^{k-1})^{(n)}&=(k-1)^n\,e^{kx}\\
(f^{k+1})^{(n)}&=(k+1)^n\,e^{kx}
\end{align*}$$
It is clear that the inequality in the title does not hold.

Comment: Sorry I have made a mistake in the statement, I miss a square on the left side.